# Java Library for Steady State Solution for DTMCs

Tags: java, eigenvector, markov-chains

I have been using [jMarkov](http://www.jmarkov.org/) for analyzing CTMCs. This appears to be the most well defined Java library for this purpose. One of the part in my analysis also requires Steady State Solution of a DTMC. Though jMarkov manual mentions that it can handle DTMCs as well but the authors seem to have ignored the case. The documentation of the library, hence, seems to be incomplete.

Can someone guide me through jMarkov OR point me to a part in the manual that can be useful? If there exists another library I could use, that would be great as well. Additionally, I would be okay if someone could point me to a Java implementation that just helps me find Eigenvector of a Matrix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not for you but for someone else who wants to try jMarkov, there are thw possible solutions for this issue:

First, i think jMarkov claims to handle DTMC as any DTMC can be transformed into a CTMC in a normalization process. So you have to transform your DTMC into a CTMC in order to take advantage of jMarkov.

Second, I'm sure jMarkov also allows to handle DTMC without normalization. If you specify your problem a little bit we could build an example from your problem.

Regards,